# Calculating FIRST sets by hand

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

I'm having a slight problem that's been bugging me for quite some time now and I haven't been able to find a suitable answer online.

Given a grammar:

`S = Sc | Eab | Db | b`
`D = EDcD | ca | ɛ`
`E = dE | DY`
`Y = Ed | Dad | ɛ`

To find the FIRST set of say Y, so FIRST(Y), am I correct in assuming that it goes like this:

`FIRST(Y)` 
`= FIRST(Ed) ∪ FIRST(Dad) ∪ FIRST(ɛ)`
`= FIRST(E) ∪ (FIRST(D)\{ɛ}) ∪ FIRST(ad) ∪ {ɛ}`
`= FIRST(E) ∪ (FIRST(D)\{ɛ}) ∪ {a, ɛ}`

Now the question is how do I find FIRST(E) and FIRST(D)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the problem with FIRST(E) and FIRST(D) is that E and D reference one another. And the solution is the usual one when you want a sort of "least fixed point" -- start with everything empty and keep iterating until they stabilize.

That is: first of all, initialize all your FIRST sets to the empty set. Now, repeatedly, consider each production and pretend your current estimates for the non-terminal's FIRST sets are the truth. (In reality, they will typically be "underestimates".) Work out what the production tells you about the FIRST set of its LHS, and update your estimate of that non-terminal's FIRST set accordingly. Keep doing this, processing all the productions in turn, until you've gone through all of them and your estimates haven't changed. At that point, you're done.

In this case, here's how it goes (assuming I haven't goofed, of course). The first pass produces successively S: {b}, D: {c,ɛ}, E: {c,d}, Y: {c,d,ɛ}. The second produces successively S: {b,c,d}, D: {c,d,ɛ}, E: {c,d,ɛ}, Y: {c,d,ɛ}. The third doesn't change any of those, so those are the final answers.

Comment: Will this method, of calculating FIRST, always gives us the correct FIRST set for each and every non_terminal? OR we should use this method only in situation like these when two non_terminals are referencing each other?

Comment: If no two nonterminals ever reference one another (directly or indirectly), then the same procedure works and it's more obvious that it works :-). Imagine drawing an arrow from each symbol (terminal or not) to each other thing that depends on it. If you have no "loops" of dependencies, then what happens is that the correct FIRST sets propagate out following the arrows, and after a finite length of time you've followed every arrow and everything's stopped changing and you're done.